# Rendering a WTForms CheckboxInput in Jinja Template

Tags: flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I can't seem to figure out how to render a WTForms `CheckboxInput` in my template.  When I try to render the field using Flask in my Jinja template I get this error:

TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

The error has to do with how `{{ form.prefs(value='n') }}` is used in my template.  The WTForms documentation for [`CheckBoxInput`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/widgets.html#wtforms.widgets.CheckboxInput) says "The value= HTML attribute by default is ‘y’ unless otherwise specified by value= at rendering."  I get an error whether I specify a value or not.

I can't seem to find an example of how to render a simple CheckBoxInput.  Any help is appreciated.

Here's my form:

```
class PreferencesForm(Form):
    prefs = widgets.CheckboxInput()
```

Here's my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="/user/prefs/">
    <div>{{ form.prefs(value='n') }}</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>    
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are actually supposed to use a [`BooleanField`](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/fields.html#wtforms.fields.BooleanField) instead of directly using the widget:

```
class PreferencesForm(Form):
    prefs = BooleanField()
```

And then in your template:

```
{{ form.prefs(value='n') }}
```

---

The general idea is to use one of the [fields](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/fields.html) in your form class, which will automatically assign the proper widget for display. And [widgets are](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/widgets.html#module-wtforms.widgets):

> ... classes whose **purpose are to render a field** to its usable representation, usually XHTML. When a field is called, the default behaviour is to delegate the rendering to its widget. This abstraction is provided so that widgets can easily be created to customize the rendering of existing fields.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Further, a widget needs a [field instance to render](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/6557f1ea453d64d52905c04e874fd8da574e939a/wtforms/widgets/core.py?at=default#cl-168) itself:

```
def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
    if getattr(field, 'checked', field.data):
        kwargs['checked'] = True
    return super(CheckboxInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Ahh!  Sorry, it wasn't clear to me that I wasn't suppose to use widgets directly.  Thank you so kindly!

Answer (score 1):

use checked att

```
{% if r.renovacion == 's' %}
        <td>{{  forma.renovacion(id = "" + r.id|string  + "", value = 's', checked = True) }}</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>{{  forma.renovacion(id = "" + r.id|string  + "", value = 'n', checked = False) }}</td>
        {% endif %}
```